# How to find total passed, failed test cases in Protractor?

Tags: protractor, reporting

How to find total passed, failed test cases in Protractor?

Please recommend npm package which serves the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with native Jasmine framework?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't want individual it block level pass/fail report, I want overall scripts/test case failure/describe block failures. Ex; If we have 100 test scripts for execution and we have 80 failures 20 passing cases, Then I'm looking for reporting plugin where will suffice the need

Answer (score 0):

okay, if you want the number of describes failed you can add this code in your onPrepare in the config

```
onPrepare() {

        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({

            suites: [],

            jasmineStarted: function(suiteInfo) {
                let jasmineSuites = jasmine.getEnv().topSuite();
                for (let suite of jasmineSuites.children) {
                    this.suites.push({
                        suite: suite.description,
                        status: 'pass',
                    });
                }
            },

            specDone: function(spec) {
                if (spec.status === 'failed') {
                    let suiteName = spec.fullName.replace(' ' + spec.description, '');
                    this.suites.find(item => item.suite === suiteName).status = 'failed'
                }
            },

            jasmineDone: function(result) {
                let failed = this.suites.filter(item => item.status === 'failed')
                console.log('**************************************************')
                console.log(`${failed.length} of ${this.suites.length} describe(s) failed`)
                console.log('**************************************************')
            },
        })
}
```

And it will result this output in your console
[image]